# Inconsistency in a modal logic

Tags: lo.logic, modal-logic

I need a first order modal logic, where inconsistency between formulas in not binary: a pair of formulas  may be more or less inconsistent. The modal operators express uncertainty. So the formulas which would be contradictory without the modal operators can have some "fuzzy" inconsistency with the modal operators.    Did somebody encounter such a logic? If not, is there something wrong with such a logic?

Comment: At a glance, it looks to me like this paper is about that idea, but only the propositional part of it, i.e., this paper doesn't handle predicate logic: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1570868304000497 Sorry if this isn't what you're looking for, or if that paper does not turn out to be useful.

Comment: Actually, I meant two formulas having the same modality may have non binary consistency.

Comment: Say $\asymp \big(\varphi(x) = y \big)$ and $\asymp \big(\varphi(x) = z \big)$ may be more or less inconsistent depending on the difference $|y - z|.$

Comment: This sounds more like probability than logic?  E.g. maybe you want a [belief network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belief_network).

Comment: There are no probabilities. The modality I am talking about is interpreted as  "it appears that". The only thing I care about is to evaluate inconsistency between atomic formulas  with the same modality.

Comment: Doesn't modality itself allow for this? After all, we can have $\varphi\wedge\psi$ and $\Diamond\neg(\varphi\wedge\psi)$ and $\Diamond\Box(\varphi\wedge\psi)$, which can be seen as ways of asserting that $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are or are not consistent.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I need a logic with $\mathbf{non binary}$ inconsistency between atomic formulas of the first order logic with the modality "it appears that:" $\asymp \big(\varphi(x) = y \big)$ and $\asymp \big(\varphi(x) = z \big)$

Comment: Probably, I need to add that, in this logic, there are no truth values and no inference either. You can not in principle evaluate truth of the statement  "it appears that $x = y.$ It is subjective and uncertain. The logic  has only "fuzzy" inconsistency.

Comment: @Marina I'm afraid my knowledge in this area is so deficient that I do not even recognize some of the symbols you used in comments, e.g. I am not sure what $|y-z|$ could mean when $y$ and $z$ are object constants in a system of FOL. I hope it is okay if I suggest something very naive: if you write $P \rightarrow Q$ to mean "$P$ is no more inconsistent than $Q$," then it appears to me that the relation $\rightarrow$ is reflexive and transitive, and on equiconsistency classes of propositions, $\rightarrow$ induces the structure of a complemented distributive lattice (assuming that you have...

Comment: ...finitary disjunction and conjunction of propositions). So you get a Boolean algebra, just as you do from a classical propositional calculus. So all you get here is just an alternative semantics for classical propositional logic, interpreting $\rightarrow$ as a consistency comparison rather than as the material conditional. There's nothing modal here, and it's only zeroth order, no predicates, but nevertheless it's a logic "without inference" but with just enough structure to evaluate inconsistency between atomic formulas, as you asked for. Could this be useful to you?

Comment: P.S. What I am proposing would of course require a different notion of model from what is found in classical propositional calculus. The Lindenbaum-Tarski algebra of a propositional calculus of the kind I am describing would be a Boolean algebra, but of course you do care about the distinction between propositions which are equiconsistent, so whatever you might decide a model of such a propositional calculus ought to be, a model probably shouldn't have to factor through the Lindenbaum-Tarski algebra of the calculus, and so the models might not be readily describable in Boolean-algebraic terms.

Comment: @A.S.    Thank you for your response. I have already a preprint of the text with the logic I need. It is here https://www.researchgate.net/publication/352414649_Logic_of_Machine_Learning

Comment: The Nonjudgemental logic I proposed has axioms about measures of inconsistency. The goal was to formalize criteria used in machine learning. It works for this purpose. Since I did not specialize in logic, I wanted to be sure that the description makes sense. Perhaps, you take a look at it and tell me, if it is clear or if it makes sense? Thank you.